# Understanding EXPLAIN to create column index based on

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have this `update` query:

```
explain UPDATE
qanda AS ans1
JOIN qanda AS ans2 ON ans2.related = ans1.related
JOIN qanda AS ques ON ans2.related = ques.id
SET ans1.acceptedanswer = IF( ans1.id <> 3, 0, IFNULL( ans1.acceptedanswer, 0 ) ^ b'1' ),
ans1.aadate = IF( ans1.id <> 3, ans1.aadate, 4353)
WHERE ques.author_id = 29
AND ans2.id = 3
AND ans2.author_id = 31 
AND (ques.amount IS NULL or ans1.acceptedanswer IS NULL)
```

And here is the result of its `EXPLAIN`:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  |       possible_keys       |   key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ans2  | const | PRIMARY,author_id,related | PRIMARY | 4       | const | 1    | NULL        |
|    2 | SIMPLE      | ques  | const | PRIMARY,author_id         | PRIMARY | 4       | const | 1    | NULL        |
|    3 | SIMPLE      | ans1  | ALL   | related                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 4    | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

It should be noted my table is just containing 4 rows of data.

Well is my structure fine? Or should I create such an index on such a column?

Comment: throw a ton of rows at it with a test db that has substantial row count. Now you are not. At the moment, your explain is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both questions and multiple answers in the same table?  This seems 'wrong'.  Suggest one table for questions, and one table for answers.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` would be helpful.

Think "composite" indexes...

`INDEX(author_id, id)` (in that order) would probably be useful.

I suspect your `JOIN` to `ans1` is incorrect (in a business-logic sense, not in an SQL-sense); check it.

Comment: Stackoverflow also keeps both questions and answers in the same table. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/421098

Comment: I guess that the SO logic is that Questions and Answers have 'identical' structure, etc, so it may as well be the same table.  Maybe it is not as "wrong" as I implied.